# Can't properly link to fileserver

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, href

I have a table with documents and each document has a link. These documents are saved on a fileserver.

**View:**

```
var doclink = @"\\x\x\x\x_x\" + Model.IdPersoneelslid + "\\" + Model.DocumentSoortValue[i].DocLink;

<td><a href="@doclink" target="_blank">Link</a></td>
```

With this code I get this url in my browser: localhost:59614/Home/x/x/x/x_x/827/IDE_1.pdf

I have tried multiple solutions like putting file:// infront etc but none seems to work.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I now figured it works in IE but not in Firefox.

**New Question:**

Do I need to link my fileserver to my IIS server somehow?

Comment: What is your problem? That there are slashes instead of backshlashes?

Comment: I don't get to see the file. The url should be something like file://server/file.pdf but instead I get localhost/home/view/\\server\file.pdf and this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 <a href="@(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(Url.Content("/uploads/path/....."))));"></a>
```

Comment: Additional information: 'file:/x/x/x/x_x/x/INL_1.pdf' is not a valid virtual path. This is what I am getting.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with images living on a file share. I had to create a controller action that takes in the path as a parameter and uses that to load it and return it as a `FileResult`.

```
public class FilesController : Controller
{
    public FileResult Index(string id)
    {
        try
        {
           return File(id, "application/octetstream", Path.GetFileName(id));
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException)
        {
            // do 404 error stuff
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // do generic error stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the view:

```
var doclink = @"\\x\x\x\x_x\" + Model.IdPersoneelslid + "\\" + Model.DocumentSoortValue[i].DocLink;

<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Files")?id=@doclink">Linky Face!</a>
```

I kept getting 404s when I tried to pass the path as `{new id = doclink}`. Passing it as a querystring fixed that.

In my situation, and I imagine this might be the case with yours as well, the file shares weren't configured to allow access via http, necessitating that I find a way to get to them in code since you can use the network file system to access the shares.

Caveat: This whole solution is contingent upon you running the application under an account that at least has read access to your file shares.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work either :( The problem is I can't say go to file://server/file.pdf

Comment: I fixed it to work for downloading. The way I had it only worked for displaying images in a browser but if you tried to make a download link it would try to open it as an extensionless file. Adding in the last parameter to the returned `File` will download the file with the correct name.